# How can I extract data from an XML file using Java?

Tags: java, xml

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<devices>
 <device mobile="true" supported="false">Windows CE</device>
 <device mobile="false" minVersion="2">Firefox</device>
 <device mobile="false" minVersion="3">Safari</device>
 <device mobile="false" minVersion="6">MSIE</device>
 <device mobile="false" minVersion="1">Chrome</device>
</devices>
```

From Java, if we give input as "Firefox", the output should be mobile=false and minversion=2.

How can I get this data from the XML using Java?

Comment: Did you try to search before? This has been asked **tons** of times before. In this specific case (where you want to extract a few values from some bigger XML), I'd suggest you google for "XPath Java".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).  First you need to get the XSD (or even DTD) from the creator of the xml.  Then you can use a tool like [xjc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) from Java to create your classes (and/or source code) for unpacking the XML string/file into Java objects.

Once you've done that, you can use the Java JAXB classes to build Java objects from the XML.  For a simple example:

```
(MyObject)JAXBContext.newInstance("package.where.xjc.generated.the.classes")
    .createUnmarshaller()
    .unmarshal(readerOrStreamOrFileOrURL);
```

Check out [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) for more information.

Comment: +1, You can also start with Java classes and then map them to the desired XML using JAXB annotations.

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html#dom

Check out the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's always connected with parsing XML. Try this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

Using `XPathFactory` you could do:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("Devices.xml");
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//devices/device[@mobile='false' and @minVersion='2']/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; 
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    } 


    }
}
```

The output:

```
Firefox
```

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();Document doc = builder.parse("Device.xml");XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//devices/device[@mobile='true' and @minVersion='2']/text()");Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());}

Comment: @gowtham: sorry, there was error in logic ('true' instead of 'false' for mobile). I've edited my post - it works now (tested).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is using dom4j, that I think it is simpler than SAX: http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/ , but needs more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an XML parser. I recommend [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/). It makes parsing XML files a breeze. They have good documentation on how to accomplish this as well.

An example:

```
Document doc = new XmlBuilder().build(new File("path/to/file"));
Element devicesElement = doc.getRootElement();
Elements deviceElements = devicesElement.getChildElements();

for (int i = 0; i < deviceElements.size(); i++) {
    Element curDevice = deviceElements.get(i);
    ....
}
```