# Java Sax parse Unique XML tag File

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I've read a lot about XML and SAX lately but I'm not sure nor have I seen this in any examples or seen it talked about. I have an XML file and I want to get the information from it.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <eveapi version="2">
      <currentTime>2015-04-30 04:22:22</currentTime>
        <result>
          <rowset name="characters" key="characterID"columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName">
            <row name="Grasume Crendraven" characterID="92916469" corporationName="Hyperion Guard" corporationID="98372642" allianceID="99005157" allianceName="Winmatar Republic" factionID="0" factionName="" />
            <row name="Susan Snow" characterID="95325415" corporationName="Federal Navy Academy" corporationID="1000168" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" />
            <row name="Grasume" characterID="95528725" corporationName="School of Applied Knowledge" corporationID="1000044" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" />
        </rowset>
        </result>
      <cachedUntil>2015-04-30 05:02:33</cachedUntil>
      </eveapi>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the information in the row name section then pull the info I need from that string. I assume the best thing for me to do is to pull the XML section I need and then set up a text parser to get the specific information that I need to be used in the rest of my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract data from an XML file using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805840/how-can-i-extract-data-from-an-xml-file-using-java)

Comment: Asuming you are referring specifically to the *columns* attribute: comma separated values within an attribute are not part of the xml specification - no xml parser will split those values for you. Instead, you will need to fetch the attribute and then call split() on the attribute string

Comment: @Matt what would you suggest would be the best way to fetch the attribute ? And you are spot on with what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: You don't "fetch", "get", or "pull" things with SAX. The essence of SAX is that you wait for things to arrive on your doorstep.